# Xcode simulated locations GPX crash on build

Tags: ios, xcode, core-location

I'm trying to use the simulated locations functionality within Xcode to test some geofences I've created. I'm using the Google Maps SDK for iOS and also Core Location to create the fences and monitor the devices location. My GPX file also looks like:

```
<gpx version="1.1" creator="Xcode">
  <wpt lat="37.3349285" lon="-122.011033">
    <name>Apple</name>
    <time>2014-09-24T14:00:00Z</time>
  </wpt>
  <wpt lat="37.422" lon="-122.084058">
    <name>Google</name>
    <time>2014-09-24T14:00:05Z</time>
  </wpt>
</gpx>
```

The problem is that Xcode crashes when attempting to build using the simulated locations from within edit scheme and also crashes when tapping the location drop down from within Xcode console.

I've done all the normal Xcode stuff such as clean, remove derived data, build etc but Xcode still crashes.

I need to be able to test the fences so that I can monitor device location changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you are using any beta version of XCode, try using a stable version.
2. I know you have cleaned, but did you try removing the derived data and module cache, after closing the XCode? If you do it while the Xcode is still open, some files would be created again in the same context for the currently openend project.
3. You can check if your file is the culprit here. Check it against any online xml tool or try to pick a valid gpx file from the web.
4. When XCode is reopened after a crash, it  prompts you with a message saying, do you want to send this report to Apple and with an option to see why it crashed. Juts try to see why it crashed. If you could understand it, well and good. If not, open up a bug with Apple developer account.
5. Lastly, we all have seen how XCode cries like a baby for unexpected issues. Just remove it and install it again to see if this would fix your issue.